# Django - Formatting of date to update a model object from forms

Tags: python, django

I've got a form which will be populated with any data from a saved model object so that the object can be updated. However the date field seems to be pre-populated with a date like...

```
2016-09-07 00:00:00+00:00
```

I want this to be in the format 'mm dd YYYY'.

In my HTML template I've tried `{{ form.date_start|date:'m d Y' }}` which doesn't raise an error but just removes the input field altogether.

Any ideas on how to specify a date format to pre-populate a date field with?

Thanks!

Comment: try putting this in your forms      date_start = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%y'],widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d-%m-%y'))

Comment: that works, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try putting this in your forms

```
date_start = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%y'],widget=forms.Date‌​Input(format = '%d-%m-%y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
{{ form.date_start|date:'%m %d %Y' }}
```